# Power BI - Measure returns blank randomly when filters are applied

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have two measures, which calculate the same amount for 2 different columns (i.e. total for person and total for the site) and returns the person/site having the highest amount.

[image]

I have report level filters on both Person and site. When playing around with these filters (either person or site),  sometimes the measure returns blank randomly.
i.e I filtered to a single person and got the following:

[image]

**Now, when I open ANY MEASURE IN THE REPORT, and simply add a blank line or remove a blank line (it refreshes the report I guess):**

[image]

The measure will now show the proper value. The fun part is, I did not change the measure at all, just added a blank line or removed it and hit enter. The problem occurs randomly for both person and site measures.

For obvious reasons, I cannot expose many details here. Please let me know if you have to look at measures, I will post dummy ones.

Any help would be appreciated, Thank You!

Comment: Yes, sample data of your table as well as the code for the measures would be helpfull.

Comment: Does doing a data refresh also trigger the change? Sharing a dummy PBIX would be the most helpful.

Comment: @AlexisOlson Yes, refreshing data make figures appear properly, however, it still comes blank when trying to apply various filters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing the `RANKX`(Rank = 1) filter with TOP N did the thing.

The measures were using `RANKX` to generate a table variable, which was then filtered with rank = 1 condition. Sometimes, the table was not having rank 1 at all, the ranks started from 2,4, etc. I am still not sure what was the root cause of ranks not calculating properly.

Using `TOPN` function eliminated the rank filtering thing and the measures are now functioning properly.